# What is correct type reference for converting the json into java object using jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have the following json output that I get from an api,

```
{"HYR":"[{\"LastUpdatedBy\":\"Bug 101510: VMukkanagoudar\",\"IATACountryCode\":\"US\",\"MetroCodeBool\":false,\"AirportName\":\"Sawyer County\",\"Latitude\":46,\"CityName\":\"Hayward\",\"MajorAirportBool\":false,\"Longitude\":-91,\"StatusCode\":\"A\",\"DisplayNameLocal\":\"Hayward, WI (HYR-Sawyer County)\",\"DisplayNameInternational\":\"Hayward, WI, United States (HYR-Sawyer County)\",\"UpdateDate\":\"2009-03-06 20:44:00.0\",\"AirportCode\":\"HYR\",\"AirportID\":5396808,\"RegionName\":\"Wisconsin\",\"IdenticalMetroCodeBool\":false,\"ExternalName\":\"HYR\",\"CountryCode\":\"USA\"}]",
 "VAA":"[{\"LastUpdatedBy\":\"fmoneo\",\"IATACountryCode\":\"FI\",\"MetroCodeBool\":false,\"AirportName\":\" \",\"Latitude\":63,\"CityName\":\"Vaasa\",\"MajorAirportBool\":true,\"Longitude\":22,\"StatusCode\":\"A\",\"DisplayNameLocal\":\"Vaasa (VAA)\",\"DisplayNameInternational\":\"Vaasa, Finland (VAA)\",\"UpdateDate\":\"2008-08-12 17:26:00.0\",\"AirportCode\":\"VAA\",\"AirportID\":4276566,\"RegionName\":\" \",\"IdenticalMetroCodeBool\":false,\"ExternalName\":\"VAA\",\"CountryCode\":\"FIN\"}]"
....(and so on)}
```

The java object is as follows

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Config {

  @JsonProperty("AirportCode")
  String airportCode;

  @JsonProperty("AirportID")
  Integer airportId;

  @JsonProperty("MetroCodeBool")
  Boolean metroCodeBool;

  @JsonProperty("MajorAirportBool")
  Boolean majorAirportBool;

  @JsonProperty("IdenticalMetroCodeBool")
  Boolean identicalMetroCodeBool;

  @JsonProperty("StatusCode")
  Character statusCode;

  //Getters and setters
}
```

The code for conversion is

```
String jsonStr = apiCall();

if(jsonStr != null)
{
   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

   TypeReference<HashMap<String, ArrayList<Config>>> typeRef = new TypeReference<HashMap<String, ArrayList<Config>>>() {};

   HashMap<String, ArrayList<AirConfig>> configMap = mapper.readValue(jsonStr, typeRef);
 }
```

However, the error I get is

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token
at [Source: java.io.StringReader@2b82d59e; line: 1, column: 2] (through reference chain: java.util.HashMap["HYR"])
```

I believe the TypeReference I have created is incorrect. Any solutions to how I should change it.

Comment: your json value for "HYR" is a string, not an array (I think this is some bad json)

Comment: _"The conversion code is approximately this"_ -- Sorry, that is not acceptable.  Nobody is going to look at code that does not reflect what you are _actually_ using.  The question is off topic in its current form.

Comment: @RC, that is why I created a Map and the key of the Map is String. "HYR" should be picked up as the key, shouldn't it?

Comment: this JSON is invalid: {"HYR":"[{\"LastUpdatedBy\

Comment: I said the **value**, so `"[{\"LastUpdat...` is not an array it's a string

Answer (score 0):

This JSON is invalid in your case. See the part

`{"HYR":"[{\"LastUpdatedBy\":\"Bug 101510:`

There is a `"` that should not be there, so valid part would be like:

`{"HYR":[{\"LastUpdatedBy\":\"Bug 101510:`

In your case, you are require a value of `HYR` to be an array, but it is of `String` value (due to quotation). Removing quotation will indeed make valid JSON array.

Comment: Thanks @Antoniossss, unluckily I might not be able to change the API response as it is not owned by my team. Is there a work around with the current API response (i.e. with the extra "")

Comment: There is none as this is INVALID json. Report the bug. For a workaround you could blindly remove first and last quotation mark, but this will invalidate valid string values. Or remove first and last quotation mark if value starts from `"{` or `"["`

Comment: the json is pretty valid, like `{"aaa": "bbb"}` is.. One option is to deszerialize twice, once to get the string `"[{\"LastUpdat...` and a second time on that string to get the wanted list

Comment: @RC json is INVALID IN THIS CASE - not semanticly. You have missed the point here.

Comment: @RC, how would the double serialization work exactly? I'm unsure of what you mean.

Comment: what RC meant was first to get a String representation of Array and then parse that string to your Config. But double serialization will not work here because the Json is invalid.

Comment: see my answer, for clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

There are extra `"` in json at the start and end of Array `"[` `]"`. You need to remove them.

```
    try {
        String jsonStr = "{\"HYR\":[{\"LastUpdatedBy\":\"Bug 101510: VMukkanagoudar\",\"IATACountryCode\":\"US\",\"MetroCodeBool\":false,\"AirportName\":\"Sawyer County\",\"Latitude\":46,\"CityName\":\"Hayward\",\"MajorAirportBool\":false,\"Longitude\":-91,\"StatusCode\":\"A\",\"DisplayNameLocal\":\"Hayward, WI (HYR-Sawyer County)\",\"DisplayNameInternational\":\"Hayward, WI, United States (HYR-Sawyer County)\",\"UpdateDate\":\"2009-03-06 20:44:00.0\",\"AirportCode\":\"HYR\",\"AirportID\":5396808,\"RegionName\":\"Wisconsin\",\"IdenticalMetroCodeBool\":false,\"ExternalName\":\"HYR\",\"CountryCode\":\"USA\"}]}";
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            TypeReference<HashMap<String, ArrayList<Config>>> typeRef = new TypeReference<HashMap<String, ArrayList<Config>>>() {};
            HashMap<String, ArrayList<Config>> configMap = mapper.readValue(jsonStr, typeRef);
            ArrayList<Config> configList = configMap.get("HYR");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using (with your `Config` with a proper `toString`):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String jsonStr = "{\"HYR\":\"[{\\\"LastUpdatedBy\\\":\\\"Bug 101510: VMukkanagoudar\\\",\\\"IATACountryCode\\\":\\\"US\\\",\\\"MetroCodeBool\\\":false,\\\"AirportName\\\":\\\"Sawyer County\\\",\\\"Latitude\\\":46,\\\"CityName\\\":\\\"Hayward\\\",\\\"MajorAirportBool\\\":false,\\\"Longitude\\\":-91,\\\"StatusCode\\\":\\\"A\\\",\\\"DisplayNameLocal\\\":\\\"Hayward, WI (HYR-Sawyer County)\\\",\\\"DisplayNameInternational\\\":\\\"Hayward, WI, United States (HYR-Sawyer County)\\\",\\\"UpdateDate\\\":\\\"2009-03-06 20:44:00.0\\\",\\\"AirportCode\\\":\\\"HYR\\\",\\\"AirportID\\\":5396808,\\\"RegionName\\\":\\\"Wisconsin\\\",\\\"IdenticalMetroCodeBool\\\":false,\\\"ExternalName\\\":\\\"HYR\\\",\\\"CountryCode\\\":\\\"USA\\\"}]\"}";
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    // step one: deserialize the map
    HashMap<String, String> configMap = mapper.readValue(jsonStr, new TypeReference<HashMap<String, String>>() {});

    // step two, deserialize the value for HYR
    final String hyr = configMap.get("HYR");
    List<Config> configs = mapper.readValue(hyr, new TypeReference<List<Config>>() {});

    System.out.println(configs);
}
```

Works here (jackson-2.3.2) and outputs:

```
[Foo.Config(airportCode=HYR, airportId=5396808, metroCodeBool=false, majorAirportBool=false, identicalMetroCodeBool=false, statusCode=A)]
```